# Can't re-install homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm having a problem re-installing homebrew. I am running Mavericks

It started with me trying to install express.js. Homebrew had been installed on my mac for quite some time, never had any trouble with it. I used `sudo npm install -g express`, but when I ran `express --version`, I got command not found. Eventually, I found a possible solution online, and just tried to reinstall npm with `brew remove npm` and `brew install npm`. Again, I ran into errors (Unfortunately, I didn't save the exact errors) I used `brew doctor` to try and figure it out, looked up a ton of tutorials and mucked around with homebrew, and I guess I broke something.

Now, I figure I should just try and reinstall homebrew.

I run the install command for homebrew:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

It returns this message:

`It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`

So, I run

`rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`

This returns:

`-bash: brew: command not found`

I try running the install command again, and this time, it doesn't tell me homebrew is already installed.

So again, I run the install command for homebrew:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

And now I get this:

`==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1`

`Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew
Password:
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 136, done.
remote: Total 136 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (136/136), 10.37 MiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (44/44), done.
From https://github.com/Onomanatee/portfolio_Yuri_Legiest
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
HEAD is now at c253261 Commit4
==> Installation successful!
==> Next steps
Run brew doctor before you install anything
Run brew help to get started`

Running `brew doctor` or `brew help` , however, results in

`-bash: brew: command not found`

I really don't know how to fix this. And why is the brew installer referring to a repository I used as a test for a little web project? (right above Installation succesful!)

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow. Consider using the "AskDifferent" StackExchange site: http://apple.stackexchange.com/